# What is cross section in "cross section of stock return"?

Tags: finance, cross-section

Can somebody give the definition of cross section in "cross section of stock return"?

Thanks

Comment: I gave my 2 cents to the answer, but I'm not sure if your answer is a typical answer for that site. Let's see what the others think.

Comment: I mean your question, not answer ;-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Cochrane (p. 435, 2005) gives a simple explanation between the difference of looking at expected returns in the time series and in the cross section:

- Time series: How average returns change over time.
- Cross section: How average returns change across different stock or portfolios.

So intuitively, if you study the cross section of stock returns, you want to answer the question why stock A earns higher/lower returns than stock B. That's why you call it cross section: at one point in time, you check the cross section of many stocks. Note that you do not need a time series for that, you really need only one point in time (and in some corporate finance studies this is also done because they only want to explain the cross section for one shock, let's say the default of Lehman; however, in most studies, you check the cross section during an interval, probably to increase the sample size).

So for instance, if you look at the CAPM, that's a model that explains the cross section of stock returns with only one factor, the systematic risk of a stock. Since the CAPM is empirically not successful in explaining the stock returns completely, there are other models, such as the Fama-French 3 factor-model. Note that those models do not help in explaining the time series. The CAPM does not tell you if the market risk premium should be high or low today, only that given a certain risk premium and risk-free rate, how much higher the return of stock A compared to stock B should be.

Reference: Cochrane, John (2005): Asset Pricing, Revised Edition, Princeton University Press

Comment: Thanks for the answer Christoph although the question is 2 cents worth.

Comment: @hung I hope you didn't misunderstand me. I didn't want to imply that your question is worth only two cents, but that my answer is only worth 2 cents (I thought this was a figure of speech in English, but I'm not a native speaker, so sorry for the misunderstanding). Anyways, I hope my answer helped. If there is still anything unclear or you want some more info, let us know. Either I update my answer or someone else might have a better one. If you are satisfied, it would be great if you could mark the answer as accepted, so the question is off the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: Thank you Christoph. I marked the answer as accepted. Sorry for the misunderstanding, i'm not native English speaker either :).